How can I configure an OpenAPI generated API with Amplify authenticator?
I was previously using a bespoke authentication module. I configured the access token like this:
app.module.ts

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AuthModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        ApiModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Configuration,
          useFactory: (authService: AuthService) =>
            new Configuration({
              // Configure authentication token.
              accessToken: authService.getApiAccessToken.bind(authService),
              // Configure base path.
              basePath: environment.apiBasePath,
            }),
          deps: [AuthService],
          multi: false,
        },
      ],
    
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule {}


Now I have swapped out my bespoke authentication service to use the Amplify Authenticator instead.
I still need to be able to configure OpenAPI to get the access token correctly. I can do something like the following:

const session = await fetchAuthSession();
const getIdToken = () => session.tokens?.idToken?.toString();
this.defaultService.configuration.credentials = {
  bearerAuth: getIdToken,
};


However, I cannot make an asyncronous call when constructing AppModule because the function which Amplify provides to get the token is asyncronous and Angular does not seem to allow an asyncronous Configuration factory.
app.module.ts

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AmplifyAuthenticatorModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        ApiModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Configuration,
          useFactory: async () => // async useFactory is not allowed.
            new Configuration({
              // Configure authentication token.
              accessToken: (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens?.idToken?.toString(),
              // Configure base path.
              basePath: environment.apiBasePath,
            }),
          deps: [],
          multi: false,
        },
      ],
    
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule {}


How can I configure the token?
